# How do I prevent others from sending their own data to my php page?

Tags: php, html, forms

Suppose I have a registration page in my website that contains a registration form:

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<input name="...">
<input...>
...
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Then someone else made his own page and used my form's action page:

```
<form action="http://mywebsitename.com/register.php" method="post">
```

Can he post his own data to my page this way? If so how can I prevent this?

**Edit:** It seems that using a token and storing its value in a session variable does not prevent someone from submitting data from his own form (even if the token is generated every page request) by first opening my original page (so a session for him is started and a token for that session is generated) and then using that token in his own form, while still in the session.
So I think Quentin is right, data must be validated anyway in the action page before it is accepted.
Thanks everybody.

Comment: Can't you use Captcha ?

Comment: Isn't there a same-origin policy you can apply? This wouldn't allow request from any site other than those on your own domain

Comment: @Quentin gives the definitive approach. You can't stop what you're asking only limit the automation of registering by making it difficult. So the more you hassle legit users, the harder it becomes for the baddies to register. Just an idea but maybe ask for email address first, send user email to complete registering, only allowing 1 email address per registration. This would limit automation as you'd have to create new email address for each registration. It's not foolproof, but if you make them register through an email, it slows down automation and proves a valid email...just a thought

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given:

- Alice, a person with a browser
- Bob, a person with a site (you)

There is no way for Bob to control what Alice submits. Your HTTP server is your public interface and you don't control what goes on outside it.

You must:

- decide how much you trust the data coming in (auth / authz can help here)
- sanity check submitted data (to see if it looks plausible (is this date a date? is this the 3rd account registration from the same ip address in the last 10 minutes? etc))
- escape data before using it as code (e.g. in SQL statements or HTML documents)

If we add to the list of players:

- Mallory, a malicious person with another site

You can make it very hard for Mallory to trick Alice into submitting malicious data (which would arrive with Alice's user credentials). The [usual defences against CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Prevention) (i.e. tokens that are unique per session and stored in the session data and in the form as a hidden input) should be used.

Comment: Sound like the classic *"Bob & Carol & Ted & Alice"* +1 for the explanation method ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can include a token in your form that only your site would know (and store it in a session variable). Then when the form is submitted you check to see if that token exists and is valid. If it is, continue processing the form. If it isn't, throw an error.

This is also very useful for defending against [Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: This can be defeated with a GET of the page first, then a POST with the token, right?

Comment: Which is no different then going to the website to complete the form anyway. But it prevents someone from making their own form to submit the data.

Comment: (answering myself) ...Not if it's stored in a session variable. The rouge webserver would have a different session than the end user.

Comment: I think my answer covers that

Answer (score 1):

One method is to have a token (which could be a long string of random letters and numbers) that you place in a hidden input field in your form.  For example

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="345kfnakvngk3kglvnd00dsg9" />
</form>
```

Then when you process your form submit you can check to see if this token exists and it matches the token you are expecting.  Of course someone could easily check your source code to find the token so you may want to make a token that expires.

For example when the page with the form loads you could save the token to a session

```
$_SESSION['token'] = '345kfnakvngk3kglvnd00dsg9';
```

then you can check to see if the `$_POST` value matches the value in the session.  By using a new token on each page request it makes it more secure.

Using this kind of approach should go some way to stopping spammers but you still need to be careful with what you do for the form submits that you do process.  Basically a good rule is to treat anything that get submitted through your form as a threat you so you will want to

- Sanitize any data that you are going to insert into your database
- Strip out any JavaScript that may have been injected
- Only allow files with certain extensions to be uploaded

etc

Comment: Some checking the source code can easily see this token. If some really wants to sabotage you by sending false data, they will do the effort to look for these fields

Comment: ok but what if someone viewed my page source and put exactly this same token in his page?

Comment: You would create a different token every time you load the page, set it to expire, et voila

Comment: That would mean that you need a database of valid tokens. You'll also need to make them expire, otherwise 1 token could be used a thousand times

Comment: You don't need a separate database of tokens, you use your session mechanism.

Comment: What you should do is store a (unique) 'token' in the session irrespective and then whenever a form is posted you compare the value in `$_POST['token']` against `$_SESSION['token']` - unless the session is hijacked as well, they'll not match and you disregard the form post.

Comment: a very beginner question (sorry): is $_SESSION accessable (and is the same) from all my php pages?

Comment: @Mohsin - once you've started a session, yes - it's a PHP superglobal. See : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

After submitting the form, the request goes to a php page. In that page you use the below code to check if its coming from your domain:

```
if(parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_HOST) == "yourdomain.com") {

     //process the request
} else {

     echo "Sorry";

}
```

EDIT: Agree. This is not secure. Just a bad hack

Comment: the `HTTP_REFERER` is easy to manipulate. This is a bad idea.

Comment: I was looking for this, but couldn't find it anymore. Checking the origin of the request looks the safest to me. You can also add other adresses if you want to use the code from a remote site

Comment: This is trivial to bypass by live editing the form in something like Firebug.

Comment: I agree this can be unsecure

Comment: never rely upon `HTTP_REFERER` it is to easily spoofed

Answer (score 0):

Create a random token and send it along with the form data as a hidden html element. Bind the token along with the user session and validate it once the form is submitted/posted back. The other guy cannot send this random token as your server will not have that token in the session.

Also use X-Frame-Options header to avoid usage of your page as an iframe in his website. Hope this helps.

Comment: You're the 4th person to suggest using the random token. X-Frame-Options, while potentially useful, has nothing to do with the problem being asked about.

Comment: true. thought the idea is to avoid the some other guy to use his page. Without iFrame option, the page can be embedded and automated to post back to his registration form even if we have the random token. So thought X-Frame-Options will be useful to avoid embedding. Correct me if i am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: No, it can't. You can't do cross domain DOM manipulation through iframes. The nearest you can come is `postMessage` which requires the co-operation of both sites.

Comment: Just because a page is embedded into a frame on another site ... it doesn't mean that page actually resides on the other site, posting a form from `somedomain.com` will still come from `somedomain.com` irrespective as to whether the page holding the form is in an iframe or `someotherdomain.com` or not - so technically it would still be coming from the owner's site.

Comment: I meant the post message. i.e siteA posts data to siteB. now got it that it requires permissions from both sites.